# How to remove a wrong flag?

Tags: discussion

I flagged a question ([this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/354123/problem-with-wifi-you-can-help-me)) wrongly as off-topic just to realize that it was asked within the support date and that an edit made it look like a new one.

Now how do I remove my flag to not cause users to waste unnecessary time with the flag?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't, flags are not reversible and you will have to trust the moderators and other more privileged users good judgement.

Comment: Oh well, good to know.